# Improving forecast for LSTM with additional data

Tags: long-short-term-memory, time-series

There are two timeseries X and Y. The timeseries X spans the duration [1 Jan, 20 Jan ] and the Y spans [1 Jan, 25 Jan].  I am interested in timeseries forecasting of variable X for the duration [21 Jan, to 25 Jan] for that I also wanted to utilize the values of Y for the duration [21, 25].

What I have done so far-  
I have tainted a LSTM model using the two time series, but that does not use future Y values for making the forecast.

My questions -

1. Is it possible to incorporate future values of Y to improve forecast for X for the duration [21, 25] using LSTM
2. If the above is not possible with LSTM, can I perform it using another model.

The following is just an example dataset, the true data have sufficient values to train a timeseries model.
[image]

Thanks